# How to Bind 2 columns of a table when one of them is of datetime data type, need correct sql query

Tags: asp.net, sql, datetime, drop-down-menu

I want to bind Product & date together in a dropdown list

here is the sql query

```
Select P.Id , M.ProductId as ProId , P.Name + ',+'M.[Date] as Name 
from ProductMaster as P INNER JOIN PlanMaster as M on P.Id= M.ProductId  
where M.IsDelete = 'False' order by  M.ProductId ASC
```

this works if `date` wasnt in `datetime` format

ERROR i get is

> Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert `M.Date` to `varchar` before you can concatenate it with `P.Name`

If you are using `SQL-Server`, try this

```
Select P.Id , M.ProductId as ProId ,
       P.Name + ','+ Cast(M.[Date] as varchar) as Name 
....
```

**Edit** : if you just want the date part

```
Select P.Id , M.ProductId as ProId ,
           P.Name + ','+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),M.[Date],111) as Name 
    ....
```

Comment: thanks it worked, i edited yours too a little http://stackoverflow.com/a/11554870/1445836

Answer (score 0):

```
Select M.CODE as Id , M.ProductId as ProId ,  M.Code + ' ,' +P.Name + ' , '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),M.[Date],105)  as Name from ProductMaster as P INNER JOIN PlanMaster as M on P.Id= M.ProductId  where M.IsDelete = 'False' order by  M.ProductId ASC
```

Basically : `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),M.[Date],105)`

as I wanted to have it `dd/mm/yyyy`